# Cannot resolve symbol class while implementing server from proto buff - unary API

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, protocol-buffers, grpc-java

**Gradle project**

Tying to implement grpc - unary API using java-gradle project

**Build.gradle**

> group = "com.kaushik.grpc"
>       version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"
>
> ```
> apply plugin: 'java'
> apply plugin: 'com.google.protobuf'
> apply plugin: 'idea'
>
> buildscript {
>     repositories {
>         mavenCentral()
>     }
>     dependencies {
>         classpath 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-gradle-plugin:0.8.5'
>     }
> }
>
> repositories {
>     mavenCentral()
> }
>
> description = "gRPC Java Examples"
>
> dependencies {
>     compile 'io.grpc:grpc-all:0.13.1'
> }
>
>
> protobuf {
>     protoc {
>         // The version of protoc must match protobuf-java. If you don't depend on
>         // protobuf-java directly, you will be transitively depending on the
>         // protobuf-java version that grpc depends on.
>         artifact = "com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.0.0-beta-2"
>     }
>     plugins {
>         grpc {
>             artifact = 'io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:0.13.1'
>         }
>     }
>     generateProtoTasks {
>         all()*.plugins {
>             grpc {}
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

**greet.proto**

> ```
> syntax = "proto3";
>
> package greet;
>
> option java_package = "com.proto.greet";
> option java_multiple_files = true;
>
> message Greeting {
>     string first_name = 1;
>     string last_name = 2;
> }
>
> message GreetRequest {
>     Greeting greeting = 1;
> }
>
> message GreetResponse {
>     string result = 1;
> }
>
> service GreetService {
>     //unary
>     rpc Greet(GreetRequest) returns (GreetResponse) {};
> }
> ```

**while trying to extend GreetServiceGrpc**

> ```
> import com.proto.greet.GreetServiceGrpc;
> public class GreetServiceImpl extends GreetServiceGrpc.GreetServiceImplBase{
>
> }
> ```

Cannot resolve symbol GreetServiceImplBase.
There is no class with GreetServiceImplBase even in build path.

Answer (score 0):

GreetServiceImplBase is generated based on the configuration(depedencies, generated source directories) in the gradle file. Sample entry in the gradle file :

```
dependencies {
compile group: 'com.google.protobuf', name: 'protobuf-java', version: '3.6.1'

testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'

compile group: 'io.grpc', name: 'grpc-stub', version: '1.16.1'

compile group: 'io.grpc', name: 'grpc-protobuf', version: '1.16.1'

compile group: 'io.grpc', name: 'grpc-netty', version: '1.16.1'

compile "io.grpc:grpc-all:1.16.1"
compile group: 'com.github.os72', name: 'protoc-jar', version: '3.6.0'
compile group: 'org.projectlombok', name:'lombok', version: '1.18.4'
compile 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java-util:3.6.1'
}
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDirs = ["src/main/java/", "src/generated/main/grpc/", "src/generated/main/java/"]
        }
    }
    test {
        java {
            srcDirs = ["src/test/"]
        }
    }
}
idea {
    module {
        sourceDirs += file("${projectDir}/src/generated/main/java");
        sourceDirs += file("${projectDir}/src/generated/main/grpc");
    }
}
clean {
    delete "$projectDir/src/generated"
}
```

Now execute the gradle task "generateProto"